# Caching data on backend side with Django (scalable applications)

Tags: python, django, caching, shared-memory

Suppose I need to build a web application where each client will be simulating their trading strategy using historical stock data. The data will be provided by a 3rd party vendor over the internet: for example, fetching historical data for a single stock based on stock ticker through HTTP call. Also, I am planning to use Django as a back-end framework.

Here is my question: 
I would like to be able to prefetch and cache the data on the server side, so that each client's request would not need to do an HTTP call again, but get it from the shared resource. I guess, storing it in database, like SQL could be one solution. However, is there a way to use memory shared between clients in Django on the backend side? Any pointer or suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a fine thing to store in a share cache, like memcache or redis (or, yes, even an SQL database-backed cache).

You should read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/; this can explain how you can store the result of your HTTP call under a cache key and then retrieve it. The caching works the same regardless of what backend (memcache, redis, local memory, SQL DB) you use, so you can test this out with the local-memory cache or DB cache and, if you like it, move to a better solution like memcache.

Answer (score 2):

There are many caching strategies you could use here, but a nice place to start rather then storing the data in a SQL database you could store the data in something like Memcached https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached. Without more information I couldn't get more specific than that.